# Why Volley is returning null value?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

*Volley* is returning `null` value.

I am getting the response from *Volley*, but when I'am trying to return the *imageurl*, it shows `null` value. Don't know why please help.

The source code is the following:

```
 public class Mediaimage {

    String imageurl;
    Context context;

    public Mediaimage(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public String getimageurl(String id){


        String url="http://www.mytre.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+id;

        RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    imageurl=response;
                    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                    String j = jsonObject.getString("guid");
                    jsonObject = new JSONObject(j);
                    imageurl =jsonObject.getString("rendered");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

            }
        });
        requestqueue.add(stringrequest);
        Log.i("imageurl",""+imageurl);
        return imageurl;
        }
       }
```

NewsView.java File code

```
public class Imageloader implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        Mediaimage mediaimages = new Mediaimage(NewsView.this);
        contentimage_again = mediaimages.getimageurl(featuredmedia);

      //  contentimage_again = getimageurl(featuredmedia);
        Log.i("jhggggggggggggggggj",""+contentimage_again);
        synchronized (this){
            try {
                wait(4000);
             //  Log.i("jhggggggggggggggggj",""+contentimage_again);
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(contentimage_again, contentimage);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe"+contentimage_again, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code of your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: It is because imageurl is returned before the request is processed.

Comment: @AnuragSingh didn't get please explain.

Comment: you should not return the imageurl from getimageurl method , you should wait for the onResponse method to be called

Comment: @HasifSeyd So how do i do that can you please edit the code .

Comment: it depends on where you calling this getImageurl method.. can you paste that code also.

Comment: you cannot expect the imageurl to be returned as soon as this function ends, because volley retrieves the response in asynchronous way, so once onResponse is called. you are ready to do any function with the imageUrl

Comment: `StringRequest` are asynchronous, meaning that adding it to the requestqueue will not be blocking, the method will continue (log then return). An other thread will execute the request and call `onResponse` at some point. See how to communicate with asynchronous thread

Comment: @HasifSeyd Refresh your page !!

Comment: PS : That is the main problem when learning to dev in Android without knowing the basis of Java, Android is really complex and should not be seen as an easy "API"

Comment: no this one is wrong to I write correct code with editing my answer

Comment: But when i am trying to Log.i("Imageyurl",imageurl) inside try it gives exact value .

Comment: @HIteshChauhan check my answer..hope this helps u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get imageUrl with function like this. Because the request run Async and after that it received with onResponse method after a while. You have to change your method to void show some loading to user and when onReponse get called continue your proccess from onResponse method. You need an interface for call back and return it to fragment or activity. and from onResponse you can get imageURl from server and then set this to your imageView.

Here is callback interface class:

```
public interface ResponseCallback {
void onImageResponse(String imageURL);
}
```

media imageclass:

```
public class MediaImage {

String imageurl;
Context context;
ResponseCallback callback;

public Mediaimage(Context context, ResponseCallback callback) {
    this.context = context;
    this.callback=callback;
}

public void getimageurl(String id){


    String url="http://www.mytre.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+id;

    RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                imageurl=response;
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                String j = jsonObject.getString("guid");
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(j);
                imageurl =jsonObject.getString("rendered");
                callback.onImageResponse(imageurl);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    });
    requestqueue.add(stringrequest);
    }
   }
```

And here is image loader class:

```
public class Imageloader implements Runnable {


    @Override
    public void run() {

        Mediaimage mediaimages = new Mediaimage(NewsView.this);
        mediaimages.getimageurl(featuredmedia, new ResponseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onImageResponse(String imageUrl) {
                ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageUrl, contentimage);
            }
        });

        //  contentimage_again = getimageurl(featuredmedia);
        Log.i("jhggggggggggggggggj", "" + contentimage_again);

        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hehe"+contentimage_again, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }
}
```

Comment: But I need to return the values from this method.

Comment: @HIteshChauhan there is no way! you have to wait for response. it can't be done immediately

Comment: There is a way... but the callback is better ! Note that the CallBack interface can be imlpemented by the`ImageLoader` directly, so there is not a lot of update to do

Comment: Please format the code sections properly, as well as indent them for readability. I fixed it, but you have since added more and missed out formatting

Comment: @HIteshChauhan check this now it's completed. sorry for bad format at first

Answer (score 2):

Since you are trying to retrieve the imageUrl inside the background thread(ImageLoader thread itself) so you can make the thread to wait for your response to return

```
public String getimageurl(String id){

    String url="http://www.mytre.com/wp-json/wp/v2/media/"+id;
    RequestFuture<String> future = RequestFuture.newFuture();
    RequestQueue requestqueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
    StringRequest stringrequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, future , future);
    requestqueue.add(stringrequest);
    try {
        String response = future.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Blocks for at most 10 seconds.
        imageurl=response;
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        String j = jsonObject.getString("guid");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(j);
        imageurl =jsonObject.getString("rendered");
        return imageurl;
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // Exception handling
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        // Exception handling
    } catch (TimeoutException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("imageurl",""+imageurl);
    return null;
}
```

Here actually you are waiting for the future object to return the response. This way you are making the caller thread to wait until the response is returned.

**Note: This should be only be done if you are trying to make a Volley Request Already from Background Thread. DO NOT DO THIS IN MAIN THREAD**

Comment: This answer satisfies the original requirements, however I'm not sure that a beginner programmer understands the usage of future objects. Maybe some further explanation would fit here, or some link to a proper site. This way you solve a problem one time, but he won't understand why is it working, and will not be able to solve it next time, I fear.